# Is it possible to fetch gmail emails using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, gmail, vba

I'm trying to drop Outlook from my MS Access application. The main problem is to fetch emails from my gmail account and for example delete it or read the body etc. 
I know I can use CDO to send email from VBA using my gmail account, but is it possible to get my inbox using VBA?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't really show any effort right now and will likely attract downvotes until there is some answer to, "what have you tried so far?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. There is a library you can use to fetch emails from using IMAP or POP3 protocol via VBA http://emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/vb.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You would need some type of intermediate API call, such as an SMTP service, in order to accomplish this task. You would then be able to setup a CDO object through which to read/write messages.