# Using the google vba-api to fetch gmail messages from Access

Tags: ms-access, google-api, vba

I've been searching for a very long time for a way to fetch gmail messages from my MS Access application. I finally found [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825223/fetching-gmail-inbox-mail-messages-via-cdo-in-vba-excel/45265547#45265547) that includes sample vba code to do that.

I'm having 2 issues implementing it.

1) How do I "Use the pre-made GoogleAuthenticator found in authenticators/ folder"?

Is this a vba class module or an existing library that I need to reference? Where do I find the authenticators/ folder?

2) Missing references to WebClient, WebRequest, WebResponse and Dictionary are preventing this code from compiling.

Are these references contained in the GoogleAuthenticator or other libraries that need to be referenced?

Comment: Can you fix the link to the post your searches yielded?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825223/fetching-gmail-inbox-mail-messages-via-cdo-in-vba-excel/45265547#45265547